# Javascript bloqueando required

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou com um problema estranho. Adicionei a função abaixo evitar que o usuário clique mais de um vez no submit. Mas a partir do momento que adicionei ela, o *required* do HTML5 e o validate() pararam de funcionar em todos campos. Alguém saberia me dizer o motivo?

```js
function block() {
        var button = document.getElementById("confirmar");
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
        button.onclick = function() {
          if (!button.getAttribute("disabled") != "disabled") {
            button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            setTimeout(function() {
              button.removeAttribute("disabled");
            }, 5000);
            document.getElementById("cadastro").submit();
          }
        }
}
```

```
<body class="noheader" onload="moveRelogio(); getInfo(); document.cadastro.reset(); slide(); block()">
```

Comment: por que não coloca um **hide()** no botão submit junto do evento **click()**?

Comment: no seu caso acho que assim `document.getElementById('confirmar').style.display = 'none';` se o submit for esse elemento **confirmar**

Comment: claro que dentro do evento .onclick() ali que você já postou

Comment: Tentei alterar mas não deu certo, o botão sumiu e não apareceu mais...

Comment: Sumiu e o formulário foi enviado mesmo assim

Comment: [...evitar que o usuário clique mais de um vez no submit..] um clique e depois o hide, se o form inteiro sumiu então esse id='confirmar' é o id do form e não do input-submit da uma olhada lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumindo bastante, o disabled pode tirar bastante funcionalidade da sua pagina. Para maiores informações, da uma procurada na internet.
O correto é você adicionar, no seu arquivo .js que sua mastepage ou _Layout renderiza, a função:

```
$(document).on({
submit: function () { $(this).find('[type="submit"]:not([ajax="true"])').prop('disabled', true); },
ready: function () { $(this).find('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false); }
```

});

Nesse caso, todas suas paginas que tem o submit, vão ser bloqueados após o click.

Perceba que o not([ajax="true"]) serve para não executar esse procedimento quando o seu botão tem o ajax=true, como por exemplo:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnSalvar" name="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" ajax="true">Salvar</button>
```

E para bloquear o botão após o click, só tirar o ajax

O submit vai bloquear e o ready vai desbloquear.

Espero ter ajudado.